# on my HTML page div moves incorrectly on browser resize?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML part with this issue

```css
#container{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 0%;
  font-size: 0;
}

.container-header-menu{
  position:  fixed;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12%;
  padding: 0 0 0 0px;
  z-index: 10;
}

.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #182438;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.header-left-text{
  float: left;
  padding-left:40px;
  height: 23px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;

}

.header-middle-text{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size: 18;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.header-right-text{
  display: inline-block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal; 
  float: right;
  padding-right: 1cm;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 80%;
}

.menu{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #1f2d48;
  margin: auto;
  /*  padding: 0 0 0 40px;*/
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.menu-text:first-child{
  padding-left:40px;
}

.menu-text{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: normal; 
  float:left;
  padding-right: 2cm;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 18;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;


}

.menu-item{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width:190px;
  float:left;
  text-align:left;
}

.list-container{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  width: 1439px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;

}
```

```html
  <div id="container">

    <!--       header and menu bar container -->
    <div class="container-header-menu">

      <!--  header -->
      <div class="header">
        <div><p class="header-left-text"><strong>Lead Tracking: </strong><span class="header-middle-text">John Smith</span></p>
        </div>

        <div>

          <img src="menu.PNG" class="header-right-text" alt="menu">
          <p class="header-right-text">Monday, November 19, 2016</p>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!--             menubar -->
      <div class="menu">

        <div class ="menu-item">
          <p class="menu-text">Mapping</p>
        </div>

        <div class ="menu-item">
          <p class="menu-text">Geology</p>
        </div>

        <div class ="menu-item">
          <p class="menu-text">Engineering</p>
        </div>

        <div class ="menu-item">
          <p class="menu-text">Negotiating</p>
        </div>

        <div class ="menu-item">
          <p class="menu-text">Deal</p>
        </div>

        <div class ="menu-item">
          <p class="menu-text">Rejected</p>
        </div>

        <div class ="menu-item">
          <p class="menu-text">Pass</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The problem is when I resize the browser window the menu item moves and overlaps on the element under the menu, what I need is to make them hide if the size of the browser can't include all of them and the horizontal scrollbar will help user to see them

The is the menu @ full screen

[image: the is the menu @ full screen]

This when the user resize the browser window and when the overlapping happens

[image: this when the user resize the browser window and when the overlapping happens]

Comment: `.menu` has a `width` property of `100%`. If you always want it to have a certain `width`, just force a value on it like `1200px`. That way it will overflow and your users are presented with a horizontal scrollbar, as long as you don't have any css properties preventing that. I also must add that this will be a usability nightmare for your users, but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯... that's up to you